# How to halt only if shift is pressed?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

in Pharo I'd like `Object>>halt` to halt only if shift is pressed, so that I don't break down my image. How do I do that?

So, for example, I'd like to be able to add a `self halt.` into `Array>>add:`, without losing my image.

Comment: Halt what, exactly? And what image?

Comment: I tried to clarify the question.

Comment: why would halt break down your image?

Comment: Add a halt somewhere inside the compiler, e.g., and you're doomed. There's other ways …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Object>>haltifShiftPressed
 Sensor leftShiftDown ifTrue: [self halt].
```

Cool, this Textbox can Syntax-Highlight Smalltalk-code

Answer (score 3):

self haltIf: [Sensor shiftPressed]

Answer (score 2):

I'll do the following now, Merging Oscar's and Richard's solution:

```
Object>>h
  self haltIf: [Sensor shiftPressed]
```